Filtered colimit of perfectoid rings is a perfectoid ring
$\DeclareMathOperator\colim{colim}$
Let $(R_i,R_i^+)$ be a filtered collection of perfectoid rings.
Consider the colimits in the category of rings $(\colim_iR_i,\colim_iR_i^+)$, and take its completion $(R,R^+)=({(\colim_iR_i)}^\wedge,{(\colim_iR_i^+)}^\wedge)$. I'm trying to prove the standard fact that $(R,R^+)$ is the colimit of $(R_i,R_i^+)$ in the category of perfectoid rings.
I encountered some difficulties in proving that $R$ is a perfectoid ring.
By definition, I need to check the following conditions:
(1) $R$ is an uniform Tate ring.
(2) $\exists\pi\in R$ pseudo uniformizer, s.t. $\pi^p|p$ in $R^\circ$.
(3) The frobenius $\Phi:R^\circ/p\to R^\circ/p$ is surjective.
I have proved (1),(2). For (2), take a pseudo uniformizer $\pi_i\in R_i$ which mapsto $\pi$, $\exists a_i\in R_i^\circ$, $p=\pi_i^pa_i$, then its image in $R$ satisfies $p=\pi^pa$ and $a\in R^\circ$.
The main problem is to prove (3). By assumption we have the surjectivity of $\Phi_i:R_i^\circ/p\to R_i^\circ/p$. But it doesn't seem that $R^o=\colim R_i^\circ$ is true in general. And I didn't find a good way to relate $\Phi$ to $\Phi_i$ s.
